# Swift 4 - UISplitViewController - Remove show hide master toggle button

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone know how to remove this button from my splitviewcontroller? It appears in the navigation in my master view:

[image]

Comment: What iOS version is this?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the toggle button on the `UISplitViewController`:

```
splitVC.presentsWithGesture = false
```

Ref [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623171-presentswithgesture) .

Answer (score 0):

I have already worked for this issue.
Simply make **left navigationBarItem to nil in MasterViewController class**.
Eg: `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil`